# percentage change between consective columns

Tags: r, purrr

Looking for clever ways to automatically create percentage change columns between consecutive variables with the same prefix. I would also like to create similar variables for every 2nd variable. We can assume these variables represent years and we would like percent change between each year and every second year.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(xx   = c(1, 2, 3),
                 a_12 = c(10, 20, 20),
                 a_13 = c(30, 40, 10),
                 a_14 = c(23, 34, 56),
                 a_15 = c(25, 34, 56),
                 a_16 = c(23, 34, 56))
df
#   xx a_12 a_13 a_14 a_15 a_16
# 1  1   10   30   23   23   23
# 2  2   20   40   34   34   34
# 3  3   20   10   56   56   56
```

What I want is to automate the following:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(a_diff_12_13 = ((a_13 - a_12)/a_12)*100,
         a_diff_13_14 = ((a_14 - a_13)/a_13)*100,
         a_diff_14_15 = ((a_15 - a_14)/a_14)*100,
         #ALSO EVERY SECOND YEAR
         a_diff_12_14 = ((a_14 - a_12)/a_12)*100,
         a_diff_14_16 = ((a_16 - a_14)/a_14)*100)
#   xx a_12 a_13 a_14 a_15 a_16 a_diff_12_13 a_diff_13_14 a_diff_14_15 a_diff_12_14 a_diff_14_16
# 1  1   10   30   23   25   23          200        -23.3          8.7          130            0
# 2  2   20   40   34   34   34          100        -15.0          0.0           70            0
# 3  3   20   10   56   56   56          -50        460.0          0.0          180            0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it this way

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-xx) %>% 
  group_by(xx) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = (value / lag(value) - 1) * 100) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = xx, names_from = name, values_from = Diff, names_prefix = "diff_") %>% 
  left_join(df) %>% 
  select(xx, starts_with("a"), everything())

Joining, by = "xx"
# A tibble: 3 x 11
# Groups:   xx [3]
     xx  a_12  a_13  a_14  a_15  a_16 diff_a_12 diff_a_13 diff_a_14 diff_a_15 diff_a_16
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1    10    30    23    25    23        NA       200     -23.3      8.70     -8.00
2     2    20    40    34    34    34        NA       100     -15.       0         0   
3     3    20    10    56    56    56        NA       -50     460.       0         0
```

or you can do it

```
n_lag <- seq(1,2)

df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-xx) %>% 
  group_by(xx)
 

tmp <- map_dfc(
  n_lag,
  ~ transmute(df_long, !!paste0("diff_", .x) := (value / lag(value, .x) - 1) * 100)) %>% 
  select(starts_with("diff_"))


bind_cols(df_long, tmp) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = xx,
    names_from = name,
    values_from = starts_with("diff_")) %>% 
  left_join(df) %>% 
  select(xx, starts_with("a"), everything())
```